# Show that if $f[B(0,1)]\cap (0,1)=\varnothing$ then $f$ doesn't have an essential singularity in 0

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Prove that if $f:B(0,1)\backslash\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and $f[B(0,1)\setminus \{0\}]\cap (0,1) = \varnothing$ then $f$ doesn't have an essential singularity in $0$.

Of course Picard's theorem solves it immediately, but I'm not allowed to use it, only Casorati-Weierstrass.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function

$$g(z) = \frac{2f(z)}{2f(z)-1}.$$

Which complex numbers are by assumption not in the image of $g$? And what can you then do to $g$ to get a function $h$ to which you can apply the Casorati-Weierstraß theorem? Can you then deduce that $g$ does not have an essential singularity at $0$? And from that that $f$ has no essential singularity at $0$?